# Symfony 2 - How to delete a bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

So my question is how to delete bundle I created?

You create bundles with this console command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Test/BlogBundle --format=yml
```

And thats awsome but what if I need to delete this bundle?
Is there a console command to delete a bundle I dont need any more?

I know that when you create new bundle from console, you:

```
1. create /src/Test/BlogBundle directory
2. change /app/config/routing.yml file to include routes
3. include your new bundle in /app/Resources/App.Kernel.php
4. I think there is something changed in /app/cache/...
```

Now what would be correct way of deleting a bundle completely?

Its joust that using console these bundles are generated "magically" so I dont know what did this command changed in folder structure and files?

Comment: git reset --hard HEAD

Comment: The best way to do this is here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is basically the process you have outlined, only in somewhat different order.

1. **delete** /src/Test/BlogBundle directory
2. change /app/config/routing.yml file to **remove the bundle** routes
3. **remove** your new bundle **from** /app/AppKernel.php
4. **clear cache** (either by deleting cache/{$env} or console cache:clear)

If this wasn't installed using a dependency manager - that should be all.

Comment: And if it was installed with composer, how do I get rid of the dependencies?

Comment: composer remove <whatever/package> --update-with-dependencies

Comment: This solution speak about composer whereas symfony doc do not. I valid response +1

Answer (score 6):

I know I am late to answer this but Symfony has [instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html) on how to delete the bundle. This is how I delete. You can use the same instructions for other bundles you created and want to remove now.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a bundle in Symfony 3 (and higher) :

**Method 1 :**

1. go to `composer.json`, search & delete the bundle.
2. run composer update ( it will automatically remove the bundle and clear the cache)

**Method 2 :**

run `composer remove alias/to/your/bundle`

f.e : `composer remove nesbot/carbon`


That's all.