# How to delete / remove Bundle in symfony2 using terminal?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to delete a bundle from my symfony2 project , I am running the following command in terminal of ubuntu system and getting error for that and m not able to delete ,

administrator@ubuntu:/var/www/com-testproject$ `dump($this->container->get('kernel')->getBundle('AcmeDemoBundle')->getPath());`
`die();`

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$this-

If anyone knows pls help me , I am new to symfony2 .

Comment: I can´t understand how you expected that to work

Comment: You cant delete a bundle via a command, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142425/symfony-2-how-to-delete-a-bundle/25785012#25785012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a shell command to delete a bundle. So, if you want to delete a bundle you should follow the [Symfony2 instructions for deleting the AcmeDemoBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html).